# How do you get the User Profile name in a Batch File without the complete path?

Tags: batch, username

I've seen that you can use %USERNAME% to get the whole path but I just want to get e.g John Doe for use in mapping a network drive to specific folders named after the user profile names?

e.g 
NET USE h: \test\Citrixusers\%USERNAME%
but of course this gets the username as C:\Users\"Name"

So the end result would be like \test\Citrixusers\John Doe

Thanks in advance all.

Comment: I don't understand.  You should be using %USERNAME% to get the path then split the string if you just want the username.

Comment: Hmm. `echo %USERNAME%` just gives my name here on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Ok, so I could split the %USERNAME% output then. That would work. I just wondered if there was an easier way to get the Username is all.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that echo %USERNAME% gives JUST the name so I was confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How do you get the User Profile name in a batch file?

> without the complete path

It appears you are confusing `%USERNAME%` and `%USERPROFILE%`.

- `%USERNAME%` contains just the username.
- `%USERPROFILE%` contains the profile path (which includes the username).

---

#### Standard (built-in) Environment Variables

> `Variable      Default value in Windows 7/2008`

...

> `USERNAME      {username}`
>
> `USERPROFILE   %SystemDrive%\Users\{username}`

Source [environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) - Environment variables are mainly used within batch files, they can be created, modified and deleted for a session using the SET command.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.